# Jquery noty, right top position, display new messages higher (a.k.a LIFO)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, noty

Client app is subscribed for messages from server. I use [jquery noty plugin](http://ned.im/noty/#/about) to visualize them. Snippet is:

```
noty({
    text: 'Message text',
    layout: "topRight"
});
```

Messages are displayed in top right order in [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) order, but I need [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).

I feel that css trick exists to solve the problem, but does anybody knows the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unprefixed css trick is

```
ul[id^='noty_'] { 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column-reverse; 
}
ul[id^='noty_'] > li { 
    flex: 0 0 auto; 
}
```